# How to add update delete edit pppoe login in freeRadius server with php

Tags: php, freeradius

Hi all Please help me about this problem

I want to send queries to freeradius server which I want to create a new pppoe login and update Delete edit  I want that how to do it using Rlm api I wrote some code But I am not sure about this Sorry for my english

Thanks all

```
<?php
$apiUrl = 'http://your_rlm_api_url';
$apiUsername = 'api_user';
$apiPassword = 'api_password';

// Data required for the API request
$requestData = array(
    'attribute1' => 'value1',
    'attribute2' => 'value2',
    // Add other request data here
);

// HTTP headers required for the API request
$authHeader = base64_encode($apiUsername . ':' . $apiPassword);

// Create the API request
$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $authHeader,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));

// Send the API request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check the response
if ($response === false) {
    // API request failed
    $errorMessage = curl_error($ch);
    echo 'API request failed: ' . $errorMessage;
} else {
    // API request succeeded, process the response
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
    print_r($responseData);
}

// Close Curl
curl_close($ch);
?>
```